# Tweet Share URL inflation Not Working inside button click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, twitter

I am currently working o a quote APP, Jquery getJson to inflate the elementes. I'm having trouble integrating twitter's share button into my code. For some reason I cannot get it to pick up the text values from the API source when I use the attr function to change the tweet URL data-text value.When I click the tweet button all I got is a new tweet window with the hardcoded text. My intention is to set the quote + author in the text field. Any ideas to make it work? I did a lot of research and experimentation with the tweet event binds but no success

My HTML code:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/vendor/html5-3.6-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="btn-container" class="container">
      <p><a id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Quote Me</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="quote-container" class="container">
        <blockquote id="quote">Never do anything yourself that you can hire someone else to do, especially if they can do it better.
        </blockquote>
        <footer id="author">Bill Bernback</footer>
    </div>

    <div id="share-container" class="container">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Something other than page title">Tweet it</a>
    </div>


    <script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
<pre><code>var quote;
var author

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(getQuote) {
      quote = getQuote[0].content;
      author = getQuote[0].title;

      $("#quote").html(quote);
      $("#author").text(author);

      $('.twitter-share-button').attr('data-text',author); // not working

    });});});
```

Comment: What does this `quote = getQuote[0].content;` return when you do a `console.log`

Comment: @DavidR the logs are OK, i got the correct string. This log returns me a random quote inside a p element. The thing is: i cant make the attr work inside this function to set my tweet text :(

Comment: Can you try `$('.twitter-share-button').data('text', author)` ?

Comment: Sry, didnt work. I do not think the problem is with the data inflator function , I already tried other similar